# Server error when internet is off (Type 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/sqltypes:int' is not declared.)

Tags: c#, .net

When i try to validate my xml file with schema i got this below error message. Can any one please tell me how to resolve this error. I googled it, but no use.

This is the error message

Type `'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/sqltypes:int' is not declared`.

Also this is happening when i disconnect my internet else works fine.

Help!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps do not attempt to do it while you are not connected to the internet.

To accurately validate the xml, it will need to download that file, without a connection, it will fail.

You could download the files and update your own XML to reference them using a  `file://` prefix

Comment: You are correct. The schema are available here -  http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/sqltypes/